# Typeahead Bootstrap Return ID and Value Json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I need the autocomplete of the typeahead to work with the name field and when clicking on the item, the id value is collected.

```
$('.autocomplete').typeahead({
    source:  function (query, process) {
        return $.get('view/_list.php', { query: query }, function (data)
        {
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            return process(data);
        });
    }
});
```

_list.php

```
[  

   {  
      "id":"47",
      "nome":"Maril\u00e2ndia"
   },
   {  
      "id":"57",
      "nome":"Pi\u00fama"
   },
   {  
      "id":"71",
      "nome":"Sooretama"
   }
]
```

Autocomplete works only if json does not have the id, only name field, but if you add the name field as it is in the json example, nothing works. And the error in the console is `b.toLowerCase is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

```
$('.autocomplet').typeahead({
  displayText: function(item) {
       return item.nome
  },
  afterSelect: function(item) {
        this.$element[0].value = item.nome;
        $("#field_id").val(item.id);
  },
  source: function (query, process) {
    return $.getJSON('_list.php', { query: query }, function(data) {
      process(data)
    })
  }   
})
```

Comment: You should accept my or your answer ([info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)).

Answer (score 1):

> You can add all the properties you wish on your objects, as long as
>   you provide a "name" attribute OR you provide your own displayText
>   method ([source](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead)).

[Here is the `defaultText` method](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/blob/19e45f9076966dfb3fda308f0be55a5ecbb5220b/bootstrap3-typeahead.js#L369):

```
displayText: function (item) {
  return typeof item !== 'undefined' && typeof item.name != 'undefined' ? item.name : item;
}
```

Because you have a `nome` property in objects in _list.php, not a `name` property , you need to set `displayText` method:

```
$.get("_list.php", function(data){
    $(".autocomplete").typeahead({ source:data,
        displayText : function(item) {
            return item.nome;
        }
    });
},'json');
```